# NSPredicate search for join table with nil values

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nspredicate

I'm running a predicate search on a table called `Todolists`. `Todolists` have `todos`.

I'm attempting to get all `Todolists` where the `due_at (Date)` is `<=` a certain `Date` or where the `due_at Date` is `nil`.

The following predicate works fine, and gets all `Todolists` where the `Todos` are before a certain date.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = _dueDateSlider.intValue;
NSDate *datePeriod = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY todos.due_at <= %@", datePeriod];
```

However, the following `NSPredicate` search returns all the results, even though some have a `due_at Date` and some are `nil`.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY todos.due_at = nil"];
```

the `due_at = nil` seems to work fine when I `NSPredicate` search the `Todos` table, but not when it's performed in a join search.

The goal is to have this work:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY todos.due_at <= %@ OR todos.due_at = nil", datePeriod];
```

How can I predicate search a join table for nil values?

=======UPDATE======

I've attempted to use this as my predicate:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(todos.due_at <= %@) || (todos.due_at = nil)", datePeriod];
```

but it results in this error:

```
-[__NSArrayI compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001e36b0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up running the NSPredicate on the NSArray returned by running a fetchRequest.

```
// get all todolists from database
NSArray *todolists = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

// then filter using ALL and ANY
todolists = [todolists filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY todos.due_at <= %@) || (ALL todos.due_at = nil)", datePeriod]];
```